# Change Button state after selection on Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uibutton

I have an app where the user is able to like and dislike different items on my table view. Each table view cell has a single like button, which when clicked executes a like action which is recorded by incrementing the like count in a dictionary I have saved. The user then can click the button again and unlike the row, and hence decrement the like count. When the like button is clicked, the following method is called:

`- (void)next:(UIButton *)button`

Right now I am using `[button setAlpha:0.1];` (changing the opacity) to indicate if it is liked or not. **Here is my problem**: For some reason **another** table view cell is affected/changed, apart from the target cell! So, for example, if I call this method and click on the 1st row, additionally, the 4th one down is affected.

The liking and unliking is called here:

```
- (void)likeToObject:(BOOL)liked object:(PFObject*)object {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Item"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[object objectId]];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *foundObject, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            if (liked) {
                int currentLikes = [foundObject[@"likes"] intValue];
                [foundObject setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentLikes+1] forKey:@"likes"];
                [foundObject saveInBackground];
                [self loadObjects];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            } else {
                int currentLikes = [foundObject[@"likes"] intValue];
                [foundObject setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentLikes-1] forKey:@"likes"];
                [foundObject saveInBackground];
                [self loadObjects];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        } else {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
}
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**: Here is my UI/table view code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"ParseProduct";
    PFProductTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PFProductTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    PFObject *product = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    [cell configureProduct:product];
    [cell.orderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(next:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.orderButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(share:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.shareButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}

- (void)next:(UIButton *)button {
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    if (![[likesDict objectForKey:object.objectId] boolValue]) {
        [likesDict setObject:@YES forKey:object.objectId];
        [self likeToObject:YES object:object];
    } else {
        [likesDict setObject:@NO forKey:object.objectId];
        [self likeToObject:NO object:object];
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    [likesDict writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"likes.plist"] atomically:YES];
    [button setAlpha:0.1];
}

- (void)configureProduct:(PFObject *)product {
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen Shot 2014-06-16 at 6.34.53 PM.png"];
    UIEdgeInsets backgroundInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(backgroundImage.size.height/2.0f, backgroundImage.size.width/2.0f, backgroundImage.size.height/2.0f, backgroundImage.size.width/2.0f);
    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[backgroundImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:backgroundInsets]];
    self.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;
    self.imageView.file = (PFFile *)product[@"image"];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.imageView loadInBackground];
    self.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", [product[@"price"] intValue]];
    self.likeNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[product[@"likes"] intValue]];
    self.textLabel.text = product[@"name"];
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:17.0f];
    self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:82.0f/255.0f green:87.0f/255.0f blue:90.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    self.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.7f];
    self.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
    self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    if ([product[@"hasSize"] boolValue]) {
        self.sizeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.sizeButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        [self.sizeButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Select Size", @"Select Size") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sizeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:95.0f/255.0f green:95.0f/255.0f blue:95.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sizeButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 16.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
        self.sizeButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:16.0f];
        [self.sizeButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.sizeButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:95.0f/255.0f green:95.0f/255.0f blue:90.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        self.sizeButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
        UIImage *sizeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DropdownButton.png"];
        UIImage *sizePressedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DropdownButtonPressed.png"];
        UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(sizeImage.size.height/2, sizeImage.size.width/2, sizeImage.size.height/2, sizeImage.size.width/2);
        [self.sizeButton setBackgroundImage:[sizeImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sizeButton setBackgroundImage:[sizePressedImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow.png"];
        UIImageView *arrowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:arrowImage];
        arrowView.frame = CGRectMake(140.0f, (40.0f - arrowImage.size.height)/2.0f, arrowImage.size.width, arrowImage.size.height);
        [self.sizeButton addSubview:arrowView];
        [self addSubview:self.sizeButton];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a bit of time editing your question to clean up the code and English. I also found you're initialising `orderButton` and your other buttons in your table view initialisation. Each button should be a newly created instance for your table view cell! Assign your buttons to newly initialised `UIButton` instances, and set your view properties too, all inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Reason being, when you're changing the opacity of the button, that button is assigned to multiple table view cells, so other cells would also change. The reason the fourth table view cell is changing, and I could be wrong, is that perhaps that one you have to scroll to and therefore it is reloading the views with that opacity set.

In addition, I think writing these settings to a dictionary and saving that in the file system via a plist is an extremely poor design. What I would do is subclass `PFObject` and have your own custom class which stores a boolean property like `isLiked`, that way the value is stored directly to the pointer and you can assess the following actions/steps when you retrieve the object from the array and evaluate `isLiked` (which you can then change).

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it

```
- (void)next:(UIButton *)button {
NSLog(@"nextButton");

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Item"];
PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:button.tag];

[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[object objectId]];

if ([[likesDict objectForKey:object.objectId] boolValue] == NO) {
    [likesDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.objectId]];
    [button setTitle:@"unlike" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self likeToObject:YES object:object];
} else if ([[likesDict objectForKey:object.objectId] boolValue] == YES) {
    [likesDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.objectId]];
    [button setTitle:@"like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self likeToObject:NO object:object];
}
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[likesDict writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"likes.plist"] atomically:YES];
```

}

Comment: I don't see how changing the button title would work, the problem he  highlighted was that other table view cells were being affected by an action on a different cell. EDIT: Also hi Eytan!